# linux smbclient using win 7 local credentials

Tags: linux, smb

I have a win 7 machine connected to a domain (say TEST). There is a domain administrator account and a local administrator account (both are enabled).

if I run smbclient with the domain administrator's credentials then it works fine:

`smbclient -L //mytestmachine -U Administrator -W TEST`

I want to be able to log in with the local credentials though:

`smbclient -L //mytestmachine -U Administrator -W WORKGROUP`

Note, that the default workgroup name on win 7 is WORKGROUP. This worked before on XP but now I just keep getting NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable wins support in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
wins support = yes
```

Alternatively, you can set up Samba to use an existing wins server in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
wins server = <ip-address>
```

Restart the samba daemon for option one, this is not needed for option two:

```
/etc/init.d/smbd restart
```

Worked on Linux Mint 11 and Samba Client 3.5.8.